# What is the most efficient way to compute the weighted least squares estimator?

Tags: regression, computational-statistics, weighted-regression

If we have the estimator $(X^{T}WX)^{-1}X^{T}Wy$ where the diagonal of W contains the inverted weights, what is the fastest/most efficient way to solve it?

I know with OLS, the estimator is typically solved using QR decomposition, but does this method work just as well with WLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W$ is diagonal as you say, then there should be a simple matter to scale each observation (both regressors and response) with $w_{ii}^{1/2}$ and then use the regular QR decomposition.